# Измерение времени после ввода символа

Tags: c++

Пишу программу, которая получает на ввод текст. Если я ничего не пишу, то через n секунд на экран вылетает сообщение о моём бездействии. Как можно реализовать такой таймер, который будет включаться после ввода каждой буквы?

Comment: Самое банальное решение гуглится: http://blablacode.ru/programmirovanie/177

Как читать по одному символу: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542055/how-to-do-scanf-for-single-char-in-c

Comment: читать по одному символу можно и через getche() а вот на первую ссылку я заходил ранее но не всё понял. вы мне не разъясните?

Comment: Космическое решение: субклассирование окна консоли и ожидание сообщений ввода с клавиатуры. Это если винда. Другой вариант: в отдельном потоке ожидать на таймере, который продлевать с каждым нажатием на клавишу.

Comment: не подскажите как реализовать второй вариант?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)

#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

const int how_many_seconds_should_go = 2;//Интервал проверки 2 секунды

bool bTimerSec(time_t start_time, const int& how_many_seconds_should_go)
{
    return time(0) == start_time + abs(how_many_seconds_should_go);
}

void checkThread(LPVOID param) 
{
    bool bFlag = false;
    int time_;

    while (true)
    {
        if (!bFlag)
        {
            time_ = time(0);
            bFlag = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (bTimerSec(time_, how_many_seconds_should_go))
            {
                MessageBox(0, "Вы бездействуете!", "", 0);
                return;
            }
        }

        Sleep(1);
    }
}

int main() {

    string s;
    HANDLE hThread = 0;

    while (cin >> s)
    {
        if (hThread)
        {
            TerminateThread(hThread, 0);
        }

        hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)checkThread, 0, 0, 0);

    }

    while (true)
    {
        Sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: не работает, я ввожу текст, жду и... ничего

Comment: @Gleb - оно работает так - нажал символ на клаве и нажал энтер и все работает, а так как ты хочешь не получиться сделать, хотя я могу поизвращаться, проблема в том, что cin перехватывает цикл while, и отдает управление только тогда, когда ты нажмешь энтер и я лично не знаю как отследить то, что ты ввел символ.

Comment: тогда спасибо за помощь и за попытку : D